# Create InfoPath 2013 form with c# application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, infopath

I'm developing a C# winform application in visual studio 2013, and 1 of my intended output formats is InfoPath 2013 form. I just wanna know if it is possible to create a form with rules for the controls using only C# code, without touching the InfoPath designer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I suppose it's possible. The Infopath xsn file is actually just a container of XML and other files. Use a zip program (7z works for me) to extract the contents of a .xsn file and you'll see the template and everything in there. I feel like this would be a very painful process though.

Comment: @user2051770 XSN is a cab file which I can use an assembly to extract and modify the file within, however what I don't know is the syntax to create different controls with rules for each control